# Disable days in Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to disable certain days of the calendar, but I can not.

I'm using this datepicker https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/docs/index.rst.

The javascript code I have is this, I work all I need except the days you want to disable.

```
var disabledDays = ['11/29/2013', '11/27/2013', '11/28/2013'];

function daysDisabled(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(disabledDays[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
            return [false, ''];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];

}

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    weekStart: 1,
    startDate: '0d',
    language: 'es',
    beforeShowDay: daysDisabled
})
```

Comment: you're returning an array while the docs say that you should return either a plain boolean, a string with a CSS class for the cell, or an OBJECT with the format {enabled:true|false,classes:"cssclassforthecell","tooltip":"tooltiptextforthecell"}. So you can return just the bool value.

Comment: can you create fiddle for same??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just modify your function like this:

```
function daysDisabled(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(disabledDays[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: that failure dumber.

Thank you very much, it was just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Created Fiddle for you.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTMwu/216/)**

```
function initComponent(){
/* Date retrait */
 $("#dateRetrait").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  minDate: new Date(), 
  beforeShowDay: function(d) {
    var dmy = (d.getMonth()+1); 
    if(d.getMonth()<9) 
        dmy="0"+dmy; 
    dmy+= "-"; 

    if(d.getDate()<10) dmy+="0"; 
        dmy+=d.getDate() + "-" + d.getFullYear(); 

    console.log(dmy+' : '+($.inArray(dmy, disbleddates)));

    if ($.inArray(dmy, disbleddates) != -1) {
        return [false, "","Available"]; 
    } else{
         return [true,"","unAvailable"]; 
    }
}
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I will review your code, but just needed to disable the days, I will look at your code to add styles.