# how can i disable particular day in calendar with HTML ,CSS,PHP,JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: html

[image]

the above screenshot is a part of our project where the objective is to book an appointment for a concerned doctor according to the day's he/she is available as mentioned.
we want to reflect the same days in the calendar to be active/ highlighted.. and the rest of the days will be disabled.. so that no action can be performed on those days. we want to do this with the help of html , css , php or javascript.
please help.

Comment: which date picker you using ?

Comment: Please ask an specific question what is issue with your code, it looks you need a tutorial, so look for that instead

Comment: @subhajit you need to use a datepicker that already does that. Search jquery date pickers

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072968/disable-days-in-datepicker]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not a code-writing service. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/* create an array of days which need to be disabled */

```
var disabledDays = ["2-21-2010","2-24-2010","2-27-2010","2-28-2010","3-3-2010","3-17-2010","4-2-2010","4-3-2010","4-4-2010","4-5-2010"];
```

/* utility functions */

```
function nationalDays(date) {
var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
//console.log('Checking (raw): ' + m + '-' + d + '-' + y);
for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
    if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
        //console.log('bad:  ' + (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y + ' / ' + disabledDays[i]);
        return [false];
    }
}
//console.log('good:  ' + (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y);
return [true];
}

function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
return noWeekend[0] ? nationalDays(date) : noWeekend;
}
```

/* create datepicker */

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#date').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(2010, 5, 31),
    dateFormat: 'DD, MM, d, yy',
    constrainInput: true,
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays
});
});
```